# Python pandas: construct list dataclass objects from each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

A consistent answer seems to be to avoid iterating over rows while working with Pandas. I'd like to understand how I can do so in the following case.

```py
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int

persons_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'age': [32, 44, '86']})

persons_list: List[Person] = [] #populate this list with Person objects, created from the dataframe above

# my approach is to use iterrows()
for row in persons_df.itertuples():
    person = Person(row.id, row.name, int(row.age)) # type: ignore
    plist.append(person)
```

I'd like to find an option which can avoid the iterrows, and if possible, be done in a manner that has some type safety built in (avoid the mypy ignore comment).

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if thats what you are looking for, but maybe this helps:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'age': [32, 44, '86']})

class Person:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.id = lst[0]
        self.name = lst[1]
        self.age = lst[2]

df.apply(Person, axis=1).tolist()
```

out:

```
[<__main__.Person at 0x176eee70608>,
 <__main__.Person at 0x176eee704c8>,
 <__main__.Person at 0x176eee70388>]
```

Comment: Thanks! This option is about 10x slower than itertuples - so it won't scale as well.

Comment: @anerjee, Thanks for the feedback. Sorry I wasn't aware that your goal was to optimize speed, pd.map and pd.apply are not the best choice for that. I thought you want to skip the for loop and avoid the ignore comment.

Answer (score 1):

I add a new answer, because the title of the question is *map dataframe rows to a list of dataclass objects*, and this has not been addressed yet.

To return dataclasses, we can slightly improve [@Andreas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67392807), without requiring an additional constructor receiving a list. We just have to use Python spread operators.

I see two ways of mapping:

1. The dataframe column names match the data class field names.
   In this case, we can ask to map our row as a set of keyword arguments: `df.apply(lambda row: MyDataClass(**row), axis=1)`
2. The dataframe column names does **not** match data class field names, but **column order match dataclass field order**.
   In this case, we can ask that our row values are passed as a list of ordered arguments: `df.apply(lambda row: MyDataClass(*row), axis=1)`

**Example:**

1. Define same data class and same dataframe as in the question:

   ```py
   from dataclasses import dataclass

   @dataclass
   class Person:
       id: int
       name: str
       age: int

   import pandas

   df = pandas.DataFrame(data={
       'id': [1, 2, 3],
       'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
       'age': [32, 44, '86']
   })
   ```
2. Conversion based on column order:

   ```py
   persons = df.apply(lambda row: Person(*row), axis=1)
   ```
3. Conversion based on column names (column order is shuffled for a better test):

   ```py
   persons = df[['age', 'id', 'name']].apply(lambda row: Person(**row), axis=1)
   ```
4. Now, we can verify our result. In both cases above:

   - This snippet:

     ```py
     print(type(persons))
     print(persons)
     ```
   - prints:

     ```py
     <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
     0      Person(id=1, name='A', age=32)
     1      Person(id=2, name='B', age=44)
     2    Person(id=3, name='C', age='86')
     dtype: object
     ```

**WARNINGS:**

- I have no idea of the performance of this solution
- This does **not** enforce any type checking (look at last person printed: its age is a text). As Python does not enforce typing by default, this quick solution does not bring any additional safety.

Answer (score 0):

One additional option would be to iterate through a numpy array with a generator..

So for example given:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int
    name: str
    age: int

import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data={
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
    'age': [32, 44, '86']
})
```

you can run:

```
persons = list(Person(*row) for row in df.values)
```